# Add image insde CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift

So I am currently trying to add a image inside the circularShapeLayer in the below code.

Here is the full code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class PlainHorizontalProgressBar: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var color: UIColor = .gray {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    var progress: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    var circularShapeColor: UIColor = .blue {
        didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    private let progressLayer = CALayer()
    private let backgroundMask = CAShapeLayer()
    private let circularShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    // Create an UIImageView for the system image
    private let systemImageView = UIImageView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        circularShapeColor = UIColor.systemOrange
        setupLayers()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        circularShapeColor = UIColor.systemOrange
        setupLayers()
    }

    private func setupLayers() {
        layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(circularShapeLayer)
        
        // Add the system image view to the circularShapeLayer
        circularShapeLayer.addSublayer(systemImageView.layer)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        backgroundMask.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: rect.height * 0.75).cgPath
        layer.mask = backgroundMask
        
        let progressRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: rect.width * progress, height: rect.height))
        
        progressLayer.frame = progressRect
        progressLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        
        // Calculate the position and size of the circular shape
        let circularSize = CGSize(width: rect.height, height: rect.height)
        let circularOrigin = CGPoint(x: progressRect.maxX - circularSize.width / 2.0, y: (rect.height - circularSize.height) / 2.0)
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(origin: circularOrigin, size: circularSize))
        circularShapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        
        // Set the frame and image for the system image view
        systemImageView.frame = circularShapeLayer.bounds
        systemImageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "bolt.fill") // Set the system image
        systemImageView.tintColor = .white // Set the image color
    }
}
```

But somehow the image is not showing. I have tried changing the tintColor of the image, and tried with other images also. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions or ideas on how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Using layers, you don't need to `override draw()` ... it would be helpful if you show us a pic of how you **want** it to look.

Comment: Are you trying to get something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7t0h.png  ... top one has `Height: 60` -- bottom one has `Height: 30`

Comment: @DonMag Yes, like that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overriding `draw(_:)`, let's manipulate layers.

First note... we probably don't want to mask the "base layer" (the entire view) because we might want to - at some point - "fancy it up" a little bit.

And, for example, we would want:

[image]

So let's use:

```
private let backgroundLayer = CALayer()
private let backgroundMaskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
private let progressLayer = CALayer()

// Create an UIImageView for the system image
private let systemImageView = UIImageView()
```

and we will add `progressLayer` as a *sublayer* of `backgroundLayer`, then mask the `backgroundLayer`.

We'll also add `systemImageView` as a subview instead of a layer.

We'll do the main setup like this:

```
private func setupLayers() {
    
    layer.addSublayer(backgroundLayer)
    backgroundLayer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
    backgroundLayer.mask = backgroundMaskLayer

    backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = baseColor.cgColor
    
    systemImageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "bolt.fill") // Set the system image
    systemImageView.tintColor = .white // Set the image color
    
    addSubview(systemImageView)
    
    backgroundColor = .clear
    
}
```

Instead of overriding `draw(_:)` we'll update everything in `layoutSubviews()`:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    // colors may have been changed after init
    backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = baseColor.cgColor
    progressLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    systemImageView.backgroundColor = circularShapeColor

    backgroundLayer.frame = bounds
    backgroundMaskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: bounds.height * 0.75).cgPath
    
    let progressRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: bounds.width * progress, height: bounds.height))
    progressLayer.frame = progressRect
    
    // Calculate the position and size of the circular shape
    
    let w: CGFloat = bounds.height
    let circularSize = CGSize(width: w, height: w)
    
    let circularOrigin = CGPoint(x: progressRect.maxX - w / 2.0, y: progressRect.midY - (w / 2.0))
    
    // Set the frame and image for the system image view
    systemImageView.frame = .init(origin: circularOrigin, size: circularSize)
    systemImageView.layer.cornerRadius = w * 0.5
}
```

That will give us this:

[image]

and we're looking pretty good.

Except... if we're close to `0%` or `100%` the position of the circular-view won't look great:

[image]

We'll "fix" that...

Let's calculate the "progress range" - inset on each end by one-half of the circular-view width:

[image]

and modify our positioning calculations:

```
    let w: CGFloat = bounds.height
    let circularSize = CGSize(width: w, height: w)
    
    // we want 0% to have the circle-image center at leading Plus one-half circle-width
    // we want 100% to have the circle-image center at trailing Minus one-half circle-width
    let progressRange: CGFloat = (bounds.width - w)
    
    // calculate the circle-image centerX
    let circleCenterX: CGFloat = w * 0.5 + progressRange * progress
    
    let progressRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), size: CGSize(width: circleCenterX, height: bounds.height))
    
    progressLayer.frame = progressRect
    
    let circularOrigin = CGPoint(x: circleCenterX - w / 2.0, y: progressRect.midY - (w / 2.0))
    
    // Set the frame for the system image view
    systemImageView.frame = CGRect(origin: circularOrigin, size: circularSize)
```

and it's looking better:

[image]

Here's your complete class, with all of those modifications:

```
@IBDesignable
class PlainHorizontalProgressBar: UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable
    // default: very light gray
    var baseColor: UIColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0) {
        didSet { setNeedsLayout() }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    // default: gray
    var color: UIColor = .gray {
        didSet { setNeedsLayout() }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    // default: orange
    var circularShapeColor: UIColor = .orange {
        didSet { setNeedsLayout() }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    // default: 0.0
    var progress: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet { setNeedsLayout() }
    }
    
    private let backgroundLayer = CALayer()
    private let backgroundMaskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    private let progressLayer = CALayer()
    
    // Create an UIImageView for the system image
    private let systemImageView = UIImageView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupLayers()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupLayers()
    }
    
    private func setupLayers() {
        
        layer.addSublayer(backgroundLayer)
        backgroundLayer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
        backgroundLayer.mask = backgroundMaskLayer
        
        backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = baseColor.cgColor
        
        systemImageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "bolt.fill") // Set the system image
        systemImageView.tintColor = .white // Set the image color
        
        addSubview(systemImageView)
        
        backgroundColor = .clear
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // colors may have been changed after init
        backgroundLayer.backgroundColor = baseColor.cgColor
        progressLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        systemImageView.backgroundColor = circularShapeColor
        
        backgroundLayer.frame = bounds
        backgroundMaskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: bounds.height * 0.75).cgPath
        
        // Calculate the position and size of the circular shape
        
        let w: CGFloat = bounds.height
        let circularSize = CGSize(width: w, height: w)
        
        // we want 0% to have the circle-image center at leading Plus one-half circle-width
        // we want 100% to have the circle-image center at trailing Minus one-half circle-width
        let progressRange: CGFloat = (bounds.width - w)
        
        // calculate the circle-image centerX
        let circleCenterX: CGFloat = w * 0.5 + progressRange * progress
        
        let progressRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), size: CGSize(width: circleCenterX, height: bounds.height))
        
        progressLayer.frame = progressRect
        
        let circularOrigin = CGPoint(x: circleCenterX - w / 2.0, y: progressRect.midY - (w / 2.0))
        
        // Set the frame for the system image view
        systemImageView.frame = CGRect(origin: circularOrigin, size: circularSize)
        
        // let's use .layer.cornerRadius instead of another layer mask
        systemImageView.layer.cornerRadius = systemImageView.frame.width * 0.5
        
    }

}
```

---

**Edit**

If you want the "circular view" to be larger than the "progress bar" (as in the first image I posted)...

In `layoutSubviews()` change:

```
    backgroundLayer.frame = bounds
    backgroundMaskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: bounds.height * 0.75).cgPath
```

to:

```
    backgroundLayer.frame = bounds
    let r: CGRect = bounds.insetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: bounds.height * 0.25)
    backgroundMaskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: r, cornerRadius: r.height * 0.5).cgPath
```

That will make the "bar height" one-half of the view height, centered vertically.

Comment: Wow, thanks you so much! Very cell explained. I really liked this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdMl7.png. Is it possible to edit the code so the bolt circle is bigger than the progress view like the image?

Comment: @Saland - see the **Edit** at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Again, thank you so much! I really appreciate that you actually take your time to explain the code also, and the steps. +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

Don't override `draw(_:)` if you're constructing a view out of layers.

You can't install a view's content layer as a sublayer of another layer. Use primitive layers. You can install an image as the contents of a "regular" CALayer, and then install that layer as a sublayer of your shape layer. That would work.